# Create statement in JPA repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Getting below error with :user (statement )

```
@Query(value = "CREATE USER ::user DISPLAY_NAME=:displayName FIRST_NAME=:firstName LAST_NAME=:lastName EMAIL=:email MUST_CHANGE_PASSWORD=true PASSWORD=:password", nativeQuery = true)
void createAccount(String user, String displayName, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password);
```

Error:

```
Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 12 unexpected ':'.syntax error line 1 at position 18 unexpected 'DISPLAY_NAME'.
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowExceptionSub(SnowflakeUtil.java:124)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowException(SnowflakeUtil.java:64)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.pollForOutput(StmtUtil.java:434)
```

Comment: I don't think that `CREATE` statements are supported from JPA.

Comment: It seems to be making it to Snowflake since the error is a SQL compilation error. If you go to the History tab in Snowflake and check how it's sending the statement, that may help isolate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the [snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html) correctly you'll have to enclose your bind variable in `IDENTIFIER(:bindvariablegoeshere)`

So it should start with

```
CREATE USER IDENTIFIER(:user)
```

I'm not sure if this pattern applies to all the other values provided as well.

Also you'll need a [`@Modifying`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Modifying.html) annotation on that query method